# Save User's Changes or other User's Information / Notes

Tags: delphi, save, exists

In my program, the user completes a form and then presses <kbd>Submit</kbd>. Then, a textfile or a random extension file is created, in which all the user's information is written. So, whenever the user runs the application form, it will check if the file, which has all the information, exists, then it copies the information and pastes it to the form. However, it is not working for some reason (no syntax errors):

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  filedest: string;
  f: TextFile;
  info: array[1..12] of string;
begin
  filedest := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'User\Identity\IdentityofMyself.txt';

  if FileExists(filedest) then
  begin
    AssignFile(f,filedest);
    Reset(f);

    ReadLn(info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4], info[5], info[6], info[7],
      info[8], info[9], info[10], info[11], info[12]);     

    Edit1.Text := info[1];
    Edit2.Text := info[2];
    ComboBox1.Text := info[3];            
    ComboBox5.Text := info[4];
    ComboBox8.Text := info[4];
    ComboBox6.Text := info[5];
    ComboBox7.Text := info[6];
    Edit3.Text := info[7];
    Edit4.Text := info[8];
    Edit5.Text := info[11];
    Edit6.Text := info[12];
    ComboBox9.Text := info[9];
    ComboBox10.Text := info[10];     

    CloseFile(f);                                           
  end
  else
  begin
    ShowMessage('File not found');
  end;

end;
```

The file exists, but it shows the message `File not found`. I don't understand.

Comment: You can improve code quality further by using free JEDI Code Format.

Comment: Ok, but i don't see why the code is not working

Comment: Personally I think proper code formatting should come natural. The OP should learn do format code manually first.

Comment: So, what's the solution in this?

Comment: Are you sure that the file exists? Use the debugger to check the value of the filedest variable before FileExists is called.

Comment: @Andreas Rejbrand, I disagree what manual formatting is a step toward an automated formatting. Anyway, solution is to manually verify the filename and existence of referenced file. W/o real debugging it can be done by adding `ShowMessage(destfile)` line before `if`

Comment: @user539484: Then we agree on that part at least.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I took the liberty of formatting the code for you. Do you see the difference ([before](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16539600/1), [after](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16539600/2))? Also, if I were you, I would name the controls better. Instead of `Edit1`, `Edit2`, `Edit3` etc. you could use `eFirstName`, `eLastName`, `eEmailAddr`, etc. Otherwise it will become a PITA to maintain the code, and you will be likely to confuse e.g. `ComboBox7` with `ComboBox4`.

One concrete problem with your code is this line:

```
readln(info[1], info[2], info[3], info[4], info[5], info[6], info[7],
  info[8], info[9], info[10], info[11], info[12]);
```

You forgot to specify the file `f`!

Also, before I formatted your code, the final `end` of the procedure was missing. Maybe your blocks are incorrect in your actual code, so that `ShowMessage` will be displayed even if the file exists? (Yet another reason to format your code properly...)

If I encountered this problem and wanted to do some quick debugging, I'd insert

```
ShowMessage(BoolToStr(FileExists(filedest), true));
Exit;
```

just after the line

```
filedest := ...
```

just to see what the returned value of `FileExists(filedest)` is. (Of course, you could also set a breakpoint and use the debugger.)

If you get `false`, you probably wonder what in the world `filedest` actually contains: Well, replace the 'debugging code' above with this one:

```
ShowMessage(filedest);
Exit;
```

Then use Windows Explorer (or better yet: the command prompt) to see if the file really is there or not.

Comment: @user2296565: That's why I gave you an alternative to 'proper' debugging, using `ShowMessage(BoolToStr(...`.

Comment: You should learn to use the debugger before asking a question

Comment: @user2296565: A debugger is extremely useful - one of the most important parts of the IDE. Why not post a question, 'How do I use the Delphi debugger?' It would make a good community wiki question, and you'd learn a lot of useful stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to mention an another possibility to output a debug message (assuming we do not know how to operate real debugger yet):

```
  { ... }
  filedest := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'User\Identity\IdentityofMyself.txt';

  AllocConsole;                   // create console window (uses Windows module) - required(!)
  WriteLn('"' + filedest + '"');  // and output the value to verify

  if FileExists(filedest) then
  { ... }
```